# Same colors for lines in a for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running the following code in R

```
for (i in Object){
  data_temp <- gem %>%
    filter(description == i)
  
  ggplot(data_temp, aes(Month, mean, colour = Year)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 12, by = 1))
  print(last_plot())
  
  ggsave(paste0("./graphs/",i,".png"))  
  
}
```

This results in a graph for every unique value in objects. But the problem is that every object does not have values in every year so the years have different colors in all the graphs. How can i get the same color for every year in every graph?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can pass a named vector of colours to a manual scale: `scale_colour_manual(values = c("2020" = "green", ...))`. Or as the limits in e.g. `scale_colour_discrete(limits = as.character(1990:2000))`.

Comment: Another alternative: make `Year` a factor before running the loop. Then you'll always have the same levels across the board ;)

Comment: Yes but in order to also have the same colours across plot you'd need to specify `scale_colour_discrete(drop = FALSE)`.